# Importing Excel in python

Tags: python, excel, import-from-excel

I am trying to import Excel data in python with :

```
import pandas as pd  
file = pd.ExcelFile('F:/MAschinenbau/Bachelorarbeit - ABSMAT.xls)  
H2 = file.parse("H2")
```

but I am getting a following error:

```
File "C:\Users\pradeep\Anaconda3\lib\site-  
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile  
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "F:/MAschinenbau/Bachelorarbeit/Bachelorarbeit.py", line 10  
file = pd.ExcelFile('F:/MAschinenbau/Bachelorarbeit - ABSMAT.xls)  
                                                                 ^

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Does anybody knows what it is trying to say and how could I fix it ?

Comment: Looks to me like an error in the file you're trying to read in and execute: `pd.ExcelFile('F:/MAschinenbau/Bachelorarbeit - ABSMAT.xls)` looks like it's missing a close `'` after your string ending in ...`.xls`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is stating that you missed `'` (single quote) after the .xls file name in `pd.Excelfile` function.